# Immutablejs Map.update breaks unit tests

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai, immutable.js, chai-immutable

I'm trying to pick up Redux and the tutorial I am following uses ImmutableJs.  I am totally new to ImmutableJs and am just going by the API documentation to get going.  My practice app is much more complex than the tutorial so I've gone off the road a bit and may have gotten lost.

Any time I use the Map.update() method, I am unable to find a way to successfully test my code.  Here is a test I wrote trying to figure out what is wrong:

```
import chai, {expect} from 'chai';
import chaiImmutable from 'chai-immutable';
import {List, Map} from 'immutable';

chai.use(chaiImmutable);

describe("Immutable Test Issues", () => {

  it("should present accurate immutable equality", () => {

    // -- Maps with Lists match just fine    
    const a1 = Map({ test: 1, args: List([1, 2]) });
    const a2 = Map({ test: 1, args: List([1, 2]) });
    expect(a1).to.equal(a2); // pass

    // -- Maps with Lists of Maps match just fine
    const ba = { pid: 100, arg: 2 };
    const bb = { pid: 101, arg: 5 };
    const b1 = Map({ test: 1, args: List([Map(ba), Map(bb)]) });
    const b2 = Map({ test: 1, args: List([Map(ba), Map(bb)]) });
    expect(b1).to.equal(b2); // pass

    // -- using Map.update()
    const ea = { pid: 100, arg: 2 };
    const eb = { pid: 101, arg: 4 };
    const e1 = Map({ test: 1 }).update('args', List(), l => l.push([Map(ea), Map(eb)]));
    const e2 = Map({ test: 1 }).update('args', List(), l => l.push([Map(ea), Map(eb)]));
    expect(e1).to.equal(e2); // fail
    expect(e1.get('args')).to.equal(List().push([Map(ea), Map(eb)])); // fail
  });
});
```

I'm using the following:

- node: v6.3.1 and v4.4.0 (separate workstations)
- mocha: v3.0.2
- chai: v3.5.0
- chai-immutable: v1.6.0
- immutable: v3.8.1
- babel-core: v6.13.2
- babel-preset-es2015: 6.13.2

My other tests so far are passing fine, only when I use `Map.update()` do I end up with this issue.  I also have not seen anywhere yet in the tutorial where this method is used, however, it seems pretty fundamental and I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more digging in the chai-immutable issues on GitHub, found my issue was mixing mutable and immutable constructs when I used `List.push()`.  Changed:

```
const e1 = Map({ test: 1 }).update('args', List(), l => l.push([Map(ea), Map(eb)]));
```

to

```
const e1 = Map({ test: 1 }).update('args', List(), l => l.push(List([Map(ea), Map(eb)])));
```

and all works just fine

Comment: You should mark your own answer as resolving your question :)